# when trying cursor fetching data in tabular form its not working properly

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

i want to just fetch data with cursor in tabular form 10g it shows just last record and also not accept a variable p_name(bad bind variable) all other are accepted p_name is varchar2 other all are number this code is work fine when run plsql

i wrote this code

```
DECLARE  
c_id C.CID%TYPE;
c_name C.P_NAME%TYPE;
c_ro C.RO%TYPE;
C_TR C.TR%TYPE;
CURSOR c_customers is  
  SELECT all CID, P_name, RO, TR FROM C;  
BEGIN  
    OPEN c_customers;  
   LOOP
   FETCH c_customers into c_id, C_name, c_RO, C_TR;  
   EXIT WHEN c_customers%notfound;
   :CID := C_ID;
   --:P_NAME := C_NAME;
   :RO := C_RO;
  :TR := C_TR;  
   END LOOP;  
   CLOSE c_customers;  
END;
```

i just want it fetch all data from the table in tabular form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is about Forms.

Personally, I'd avoid cursors and loops and simply create a data block based on the `c` table and execute query upon entering the form.

Anyway, you are missing the `NEXT_RECORD`. Without it, new cursor values overwrite previous ones.

```
DECLARE  
  c_id   C.CID%TYPE;
  c_name C.P_NAME%TYPE;
  c_ro   C.RO%TYPE;
  C_TR   C.TR%TYPE;

  CURSOR c_customers is  
    SELECT all CID, P_name, RO, TR FROM C;  

BEGIN  
   OPEN c_customers;  
   LOOP
     FETCH c_customers into c_id, C_name, c_RO, C_TR;  
     EXIT WHEN c_customers%notfound;

     :CID    := C_ID;
     :P_NAME := C_NAME;
     :RO     := C_RO;
     :TR     := C_TR;  

     NEXT_RECORD;         --> this is missing
   END LOOP;  
   CLOSE c_customers;  
END;
```

A shorter version would be a cursor `FOR` loop; it saves you from typing and handling several things (opening & closing the cursor, paying attention to exiting the loop, declaring cursor variables). Also, it is a good idea to precede form items with block they belong to (e.g. `:block.cid`) - this might fix the "bad bind variable" error:

```
BEGIN  
   FOR cur_r in (select cid, p_name, ro, tr from c)
   LOOP
     :block.CID    := cur_r.cid;
     :block.P_NAME := cur_R.p_NAME;
     :block.RO     := cur_r.RO;
     :block.TR     := cur_r.TR;  

     NEXT_RECORD;         --> this is missing
   END LOOP;  
END;
```

---

Note that `NEXT_RECORD` is a restricted procedure and it can't be called from **any** trigger; some of them don't allow such a procedures so - if that happens - you'll have to create a workaround. The simplest one is the one I already suggested - a data block created on the `c` table (no cursors, no loops).

Comment: Thanks Littlefoot yes 'for'  is best and i did with it thanks to your reply I am fan of you many forums you are doing great job

Answer (score 0):

```
declare 
c_empno emp.empno%type;
c_ename emp.ename%type;
c_job emp.job%type;
c_deptno emp.deptno%type;
c_stat varchar2(10):='test';
l_stat varchar2(10);
cursor c_emp_data is select empno, ename, job, deptno, c_stat
  from emp;
  Begin
  Open c_emp_Data;
  loop
  fetch c_emp_Data into c_empno, c_ename, c_job, c_deptno, l_stat;
  dbms_output.put_line(c_empno||' '||c_ename||c_job||c_deptno||l_stat);
  exit when c_emp_data%notfound;
  end loop;
  end;
```